# Why does Cleave numeral formatting stop after two decimal places?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inputformatter, cleave

I am trying to format in input field using a Cleave component which groups the raw input value into thousands.  I am using React JS.

```
<InputGroup>
    <Cleave
        id="format_number_input"
        value={this.props.NumberInput}
        className="form-control"
        options={{
            numeral: true,
            numeralThousandsGroupStyle: "thousand",
            rawValueTrimPrefix: true
        }}
        onChange={this.props.handleOnChange}
    />
</InputGroup>
```

My problem is that I want to allow many digits after the decimal point, but the input field prevents anything more than two decimal places, i.e. I want to be able to input `123.000001`, but the field only allows the value up to two decimal places: `123.00`.

Is this behaviour intrinsic to the Cleave component, and is there some way around this?
The component's source is here: https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js

Comment: the default decimal scale is 2 and can be changed: https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/blob/master/doc/options.md#numeraldecimalscale

Comment: @blueIDe Thanks! This is what I was looking for.